# Conserved currents in Yang-Mills theory: gluon current vs. quark current

Tags: gauge-theory, noethers-theorem, gauge-invariance, yang-mills

In Yang-Mills theory there are two currents we can construct. There is the well-known quark current related to the global $SU(3)_C$ symmetry,
$$j{}^{\mu\,A}_\text{quark} = \overline{\psi}{}^i \gamma{}^\mu \left(\hat{t}{}^A\right){}^j{}_i \psi{}_j \, .
$$
On the other hand, we can also write down the expression
$$j{}^{\mu\,A}_\text{gluon} = f{}^{ABC} F{}^{\mu\nu}{}_B A{}_{\nu C} \, , $$ 
where $f{}_{AB}{}^C$ are the $SU(3)_C$ structure constants, and the Killing metric $\delta{}^{AB} = \tfrac12 \text{Tr}\left( \hat{t}{}^A \hat{t}{}^B \right)$ was used to raise two indices to obtain $f{}^{ABC} = \delta{}^{AI} \delta{}^{BJ} f{}_{IJ}{}^C$.

My question: what is the physical interpretation of this ''gluon current?'' Is it related to some symmetry as well?